# Call imported function in python using string

Tags: python

I have a list of the names of imported functions, which I can call as follows:

```
from myfile import function1
from myfile import function2

function1()
function2()
```

How would I call the functions from a list of names? For example:

```
fns = ['function1', 'function2']
for fn in fns:
    fn()
```

How would I do the above properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

don't use a list of strings, just store the functions in the list:

```
fns = [function1, function2]
for fn in fns:
    fn()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access to function objects from `globals()` namespace, but note that this is not a general approach, since first of all your imported objects should be callable (have `__call__` attribute) and they should be present in global name space.:

```
for fn in fns:
    try:
        globals()[fn]()
    except KeyError:
        raise Exception("The name {} is not in global namespace".format(fn))
```

Example:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations, permutations
>>> 
>>> l = ['combinations', 'permutations']
>>> for i in l:
...     print(list(globals()[i]([1, 2, 3], 2)))
... 
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (3, 2)]
```

Comment: I do not recommend using introspection tools for production code, there are many cases where this won't necessarily work as expected such as trying importing the module itself won't work: `import math l globals()["math.sqrt"](4)`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Indeed, I was updating the answer.